# How to set a background image for the header

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I use IEEE latex file for a conference. The conference has provided a Mircosoft Word template for the paper that matches the IEEE tex file but it has a background on the header as follows, which is repeated on all pages:

[image]

The top margin is "1.38 inch", I used `fancyhdr` package as follows to set the background:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength\headheight{1.38in} 

\rhead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{head}}
```

It creates a header with the image, however the image is not faded as it is in the word document, but more importantly, it shifts the text to the bottom as follows:

[image]

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use the `background` package by Gonzalo Medina and use `fading` by `opacity=0.2` (for example)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{kbei.jpg}},scale=1,placement=top,opacity=0.2,position={8.3cm,1cm}}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the fading, if you use pdflatex, you could use

```
\usepackage{transparent}
```

you could use scrlayers

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}

\DeclareNewLayer[% define a new layer
background,
head,
contents=\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{head}
]{myheader}
```

And then

```
\AddLayersToPageStyle{empty}{myheader}
```

But don't forget to remove the layer from following pages if you don't need it anymore

```
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{empty}{myheader}% remove the layer
```

If you would have had a MWE it would have been easier to answer more specific.